# Having trouble getting a Hibernate JUnit test to generate a constraint exception

Tags: mysql, hibernate, junit

I'm using Hibernate 4.0.1.Final with a MySQL 5.5 database.  I'm writing a Java console app.  In a JUnit test, I'm having trouble getting a test to fail.  Here's my models under test …

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ic_domain")
public class Domain {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DOMAIN_ID")
    private String domainId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Organization.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORGANIZATION_ID")
    private Organization org;
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ic_organization")
public class Organization {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ORGANIZATION_ID")
    private String organizationId;
```

My problem is, in my JUnit test, I'm trying to create a foreign key that doesn't exist, expecting things to fail upon saving, but they never do.  Here's the JUnit test

```
@Test
public void testSaveDomainWithUnmathcedOrg() { 
    final Organization org = createDummyOrg();
    // Create an org id that doesn't exist.
    org.setOrganizationId("ZZZZ");
    final Domain domain = new Domain();
    final String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
    domain.setDomainId(id);
    domain.setName(org.getName());
    domain.setOrg(org);
    m_domainDao.saveOrUpdate(domain);   
}   // testSaveDomainWithUnmatchedOrg
```

The code of the DAO is

```
public void saveOrUpdate(final Domain domain) {
    final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.saveOrUpdate(obj);
}   // saveOrUpdate
```

Shouldn't things fail at "session.saveOrUpdate"?  How do I make them?  I don't want to commit my data in the JUnit test because I don't want to pollute the underlying database with dummy data, but if that is the only way, so be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to commit, but you need to flush the session to trigger execution of SQL statements:

```
m_domainDao.saveOrUpdate(domain);    
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
```

Then you can roll the transaction back if you don't want to pollute the database.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect things to fail?

You create a new Domain and save it.  Should work as expected.

Domain has a mapping to Organization. You have not stated any @Cascade options so I would guess no insert is made to the Organisation table. Add save-update Cascade options on the one-to-one and I would expect both Domain and Organisation are saved as expected with no issues.

Only issue I can see is if you tried to save the Organisation as the parent Domain would not exist in the database. But then you wouldn't want to do that anyway.

I would suggest maintaining a seperate DB for testing and using something like DBUnit to set up the data for each test run.

http://www.dbunit.org/

I typically use this with Spring's transactional test support and Hibernate's DDL value to to 'create' so the test database automatically updates with every schema change.